# Combining two functions into one function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to combine these two functions.

Can someone tell my how? I've tried it but I can't find a good solution.
These Functions do the same task. So I want to combine these.

Details:-

Here is my Code:-

```
var bg = $("#metadescription").on('keyup', function(){
var maxlength = $(this).attr("data-limit");
var percentage = Math.floor($(this).val().length / maxlength * 100) + '%';
$(".spanbg1").css("width", percentage);
var $span1 = $(".spanbg1");
var lengthScope = 10;

if ($(this).val().length > maxlength)
{

 $span1.css("background-color", "#fc3636");

}
 else if ($(this).val().length > maxlength-lengthScope)
{                         
 $span1.css("background-color", "#ffb14d");
 }
 else
 {                                
 $span1.css("background-color", "#76e07a");
 }

 });


 var bg = $("#title").on('keyup', function(){
 var maxlength = $(this).attr("data-limit");
 var lengthScope = 10;
 var $span = $(".spanbg");
 var percentage = Math.floor($(this).val().length / maxlength * 100) + '%';
 $span.css("width", percentage);

 if ($(this).val().length > maxlength)
 {

  $span.css("background-color", "#fc3636");

  }
  else if ($(this).val().length > maxlength-lengthScope)
  {                               
$span.css("background-color", "#ffb14d");
  }
  else
   {                               
   $span.css("background-color", "#76e07a");
   }

   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var bg = $("#metadescription, #title").on('keyup', function(){

  //your common code here

  var $span = ($(this).attr('id')=="metadescription" ? $(".spanbg1") : $(".spanbg"));

 //your common code here

 });
```

Updated answer with @iHasCodeForU **ternary expression**

Comment: But then when i type something in both background change

Comment: Since var $span are different in both functions, this does not solve the issue.

Comment: In my original code has one of them the class ".spanbg1" and the other one ".spanbg"

Comment: `var $span = ($(this).attr('id')=="metadescription" ? $(".spanbg1") : $(".spanbg"))` might help

Comment: @Lain i like my highly logical logic :)

Comment: @iHasCodeForU: Oh it is logical indeed. Just a bit.. undynamic :p

Comment: @Rajashekhar: But it's not flexible.

Answer (score 0):

try this,
**Code which is common in both function put directly and other code place inside if condition something like this**

```
if($(this).attr("id") == "title") {
 // code related to title id
}
else {
}



var bg = $("#metadescription,#title").on('keyup', function(){
  var maxlength = $(this).attr("data-limit");
  var lengthScope = 10;
  var $span = $(".spanbg");
  var $span1 = $(".spanbg1");
  var percentage = Math.floor($(this).val().length / maxlength * 100) + '%';

  if($(this).attr("id") == "title") {
    $span.css("width", percentage);

    if ($(this).val().length > maxlength) {
     $span.css("background-color", "#fc3636");
   }
   else if ($(this).val().length > maxlength-lengthScope) {                               
     $span.css("background-color", "#ffb14d");
   }
  else {                               
    $span.css("background-color", "#76e07a");
  }
}
else {
 if ($(this).val().length > maxlength) {
   $span1.css("background-color", "#fc3636");
 }
 else if ($(this).val().length > maxlength-lengthScope) {                         
   $span1.css("background-color", "#ffb14d");
 }
 else {                                
  $span1.css("background-color", "#76e07a");
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
var bg = $("#metadescription, #title").on('keyup', function() {
var maxlength = $(this).attr("data-limit");
var lengthScope = 10;
var targetSpan = $(this).attr("data-target-span");
var $span = $("."+targetSpan);
var percentage = Math.floor($(this).val().length / maxlength * 100) + '%';
$span.css("width", percentage);

if ($(this).val().length > maxlength) {
    $span.css("background-color", "#fc3636");
} else if ($(this).val().length > maxlength - lengthScope) {
    $span.css("background-color", "#ffb14d");
} else {
    $span.css("background-color", "#76e07a");
}
```

});

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" id="metadescription" data-target-span="spanbg1" >
<span class="spanbg1"></span>
<input type="text" id="title" data-target-span="spanbg" >
<span class="spanbg"></span>
```